# Failed to set file modification time, path = './pubspec.lock' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)

Tags: docker, flutter, gitlab-ci

I am setting up the CI for the Flutter project using Gitlab CI. Project uses a code generation backed library, so we need to run `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` to generate all the necessary code.

After executing this two script entries:

`- flutter packages get
 - flutter packages pub run build_runner build`

the script gives an error message saying `Failed to set file modification time, path = './pubspec.lock' (OS Error: Operation not permitted, errno = 1)`.

`sudo chmod 777 pubspec.lock` or `a+w` did not help. `chown` did not help, too (taking into account that `echo $USER` returned an empty string, which is questionable for me). I just ran out of ideas, I thought that `chmod` should remove all the problems with file access.

[I am using this docker image.](https://hub.docker.com/r/cirrusci/flutter)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Bitbucket pipeline, run the flutter command from the absolute path directly works for me:

```
sudo /home/cirrus/sdks/flutter/bin/flutter packages pub run build_runner build
```